# Write To a specific line of a file in a loop using batch script

Tags: windows-7, script

I want to write some text in specific lines of a file, for example I want to write in lines 12 and 13, and also I need to do this every 5 seconds.

How to do it using batch script?

Comment: There’s no simple built-in way to do that. You cannot use built-in commands to modify only the desired lines. The best you can do with built-in commands is to read the whole file, and write it back out to a temporary file with `for`, using `set` to keep a counter so that you can write something different that what is in the original files, then overwrite the original with the temp file. Can you use an external third-party tool?

Answer (score 0):

if you have possibility to install cygwin or msys then you could use sed script i.e.:

```
while :; do sleep 5; sed -e "12s/.*/replaced/" somefile.txt; done
```

will replace line 12 of somefile.txt with "replaced" every 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

It is possible and interestingly the simplest way (imho) to do it is to use *nix tools, [sed from the GnuWin32 project](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) in this instance. With that you do the following from `cmd.exe`:

```
\path\to\sed.exe -i -e '12s/.*/replaced/' \path\with\files\*
```